# SQL select menus which have no submenu

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have Table in SQL SERVER having **Title**, **ID** and **refer**. The **refer** indicates that this item is submenu of which other.

sample table:

ID   |  Refer  |   Title

1    |   0   |   menu 1

2    |    0  |   menu 2

3    |   1   |   submenu of 1

4    |   1   |   submenu of 1

I need a query to select items which has no submenu (in this case menu 2). I have solved it by asp code which counts submenus and omits unwanted results but I need a *pure SQL query*.

Comment: how do differentiate menu1 and menu2?

Comment: 3 and 4 are submenu of menu1, but menu2 has no submenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0364d/1)

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM YOURTABLE T1 LEFT JOIN YOURTABLE T2 ON T1.ID = T2.REFER
WHERE T2.REFER IS NULL AND T1.REFER=0
```

Comment: My tables T1 and T2 are the same. Can I left join table by itself?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour : yes, you can. that is called self-join.

Answer (score 1):

This query gives you all items without children:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Refer, t1.Title
from MyTable t1
left join MyTable t2 on t1.ID = t2.Refer
where t2.Refer is null
```

If you want only top-level items, the query below should do it:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Refer, t1.Title
from MyTable t1
left join MyTable t2 on t1.ID = t2.Refer
left join MyTable t3 on t3.ID = t1.Refer
where t2.Refer is null
    and t3.ID is null
```